# Why does predict.glmnet ignore the lambda value that is passed to it, and is there a workaround to make it accept the value?

Tags: r, glmnet

In the following code, I would expect the two print statements to print the same result, since I am explicitly passing the parameter `s` to both predict functions.

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(1)
x=rnorm(100)
eps=rnorm(100)

y = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + eps

xmat=model.matrix(y~poly(x,10,raw=T),data=data.frame(x=x))

grid=10^seq(10,-2,length=100)

lasso.mod = glmnet(xmat,y, alpha=1,lambda=grid)
lasso.coef=predict(lasso.mod,type="coefficients",s=0.01495444)[1:10,]
print(lasso.coef)

lasso.mod = glmnet(xmat,y, alpha=1,lambda=5)
lasso.coef=predict(lasso.mod,type="coefficients",s=0.01495444)[1:10,]
print(lasso.coef)
```

However, the results are very different, and I would like to understand why.

```
          (Intercept)           (Intercept) poly(x, 10, raw = T)1 
         1.1329454011          0.0000000000          1.3081576745 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)2 poly(x, 10, raw = T)3 poly(x, 10, raw = T)4 
         0.6887020751          0.6576599481          0.0336098492 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)5 poly(x, 10, raw = T)6 poly(x, 10, raw = T)7 
         0.0566899437          0.0002744787          0.0006870169 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)8 
         0.0001053833 
          (Intercept)           (Intercept) poly(x, 10, raw = T)1 
             2.092266              0.000000              0.000000 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)2 poly(x, 10, raw = T)3 poly(x, 10, raw = T)4 
             0.000000              0.000000              0.000000 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)5 poly(x, 10, raw = T)6 poly(x, 10, raw = T)7 
             0.000000              0.000000              0.000000 
poly(x, 10, raw = T)8 
             0.000000
```

I performed an experiment where I changed `lasso.mod = glmnet(xmat,y, alpha=1,lambda=5)` to
`lasso.mod = glmnet(xmat,y, alpha=1,lambda=0.015)`, and the results were much closer.

It seems that the predict function has a dependency on the `grid` that is passed to the training function, but the documentation seems to indicate that `s` parameter on `predict` should override it. Is there a dependency, and if so, what is it and how can I work around it to the coefficients for arbitrary `s`?

Update 1: I found a cryptic warning in the documentation for `glmnet`.

```
      Do not
      supply a single value for 'lambda' (for predictions after CV
      use 'predict()' instead).  Supply instead a decreasing
      sequence of 'lambda' values. 'glmnet' relies on its warms
      starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path
      than compute a single fit.
```

The warning only refers to performance and not accuracy / stability, but I tried to vary different decreasing sequences of `grid`, and the results of `predict` still varied.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be related to the fact that the `s` value you use does not belong to `grid`. Refer to `predict.glmnet` help for the use of `exact`. One way around it is to use the exact same `s` value you want to use in `predict` when building models using `glmnet`.